# Update combobox with other's combobox selection through JQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, select, struts2

I have a project with JSP + Struts2 + JQuery with the following functional requirement:

I have *n* Teachers that should be replaced. Once 1 teacher is selected as "Sick" the user must choose 1 colleague to replace him/her.
But, if more than one teacher are sick, the user must select replacement for all of them ... and 1 replacement CANNOT be on 2 places at a time.

So I need to achieve the following

- When 1 option is selected on any combobox, all related combos should remove that option from its lists.
- And, if any combo with a selected value is reset to default (value="") then the other combos should add that option to its lists.

First the upper code, just bellow  HTML tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

$(window).load(function(){
$(function(){
    $('.selbox1').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var sel = $(this);

    if(val !== ""){
       if(sel.data("selected")){   
           var oldval = sel.data("selected");               
           sel
           .siblings('select')
           .append($('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
       }
         sel
        .data("selected", val)
        .siblings('select')
        .children('option[value=' + val + ']')
        .remove();
    }
    else if(val === ""){
        if(sel.data("selected")){   
           var oldval = sel.data("selected");              
           sel
           .removeData("selected")
           .siblings('select')
           .append($('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
       }
    }
    });
});
});

//]]></script>
```

And now how I create the combobox:

```
<s:iterator value="listaProfesASustituir" var="listaSustitucionesAInsertar" status="listaProfesASustituirStatus">  
    <select name="selectbox<s:property value='#listaProfesASustituirStatus.index'/>" class="selbox1">
        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
        <s:iterator value="profesPrimera" status="profesPrimeraStatus">
            <option value="<s:property />"><s:property /></option>    
        </s:iterator>
    </select>
</s:iterator>
```

If you need it, here is the HTML code generated after the struts2 is rendered:

```
<select name="selectbox1" class="selbox1">
    <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
    <option value="Tera">Tera</option>    
    <option value="No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.">No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.</option>    
</select>
<select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
    <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
    <option value="Tera">Tera</option>  
    <option value="No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.">No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.</option>    
</select>
```

Finally, here is almost the complete HTML code that the browser is giving as "source code" of the resulting page (I've removed the menu and other minor stuff to make it shorter and readable):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

    $(window).load(function(){
        $(function(){
            $('.selbox1').change(function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                var sel = $(this);

                if(val !== ""){
                   if(sel.data("selected")){   
                       var oldval = sel.data("selected");              
                       sel
                       .siblings('select')
                       .append($('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
                   }
                     sel
                        .data("selected", val)
                        .siblings('select')
                        .children('option[value=' + val + ']')
                        .remove();
                }
                else if(val === ""){
                    if(sel.data("selected")){   
                       var oldval = sel.data("selected");             
                       sel
                       .removeData("selected")
                       .siblings('select')
                       .append($('<option/>').attr("value", oldval).text(oldval));
                   }
                }
            });
        });
    });

    //]]></script>
    <title>Administración: Sustituciones</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leyenda">Sustituciones para el Lunes 20/01/20</div>
        <div id="alta"> 
            <form id="ListadoSustituciones" name="ListadoSustituciones" action="/TFG_Sustituciones/ListadoSustituciones.action" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="fecha" value="20/01/20" id="ListadoSustituciones_fecha"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Juan" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir"/>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><td colspan="3"> Sustituciones para <b>Juan</b></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora</td>
                            <td id="nowrap">Profesor Propuesto</td>
                            <td id="nowrap">Profesor Sustituto</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>1ª</td>
                            <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">Locuaz</td>
                            <td class='centrado'>
                                <select name="selectbox1" class="selbox1">
                                    <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                    <option value="Tera">Tera</option>  
                                    <option value="No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.">No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.</option>    
                                </select>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>2ª</td>
                            <td id="nowrap" class="centrado" colspan="2">No tiene clase.</td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustitutoSegunda" value="No tiene clase." id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSegunda"/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>3ª</td>
                            <td id="nowrap" class="centrado" colspan="2">Se pierde apoyo.</td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustitutoTercera" value="Se pierde apoyo." id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoTercera"/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>4ª</td>
                            <td id="nowrap" class="centrado" colspan="2">Se pierde apoyo.</td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustitutoCuarta" value="Se pierde apoyo." id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoCuarta"/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>5ª</td>
                            <td id="nowrap" class="centrado" colspan="2">Se pierde apoyo.</td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustitutoQuinta" value="Se pierde apoyo." id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoQuinta"/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>6ª</td>
                            <td id="nowrap" class="centrado" colspan="2">Se pierde apoyo.</td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustitutoSexta" value="Se pierde apoyo." id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSexta"/>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Robustiano" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir"/>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><td colspan="3"> Sustituciones para <b>Robustiano</b></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora</td>
                            <td id="nowrap">Profesor Propuesto</td>
                            <td id="nowrap">Profesor Sustituto</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>1ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                <select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
                                    <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                    <option value="Tera">Tera</option>  
                                    <option value="No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.">No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.</option>    
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>2ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                    <select name="profeSustitutoSegunda" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSegunda" required="true">
                                        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                        <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
                                        <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
                                        <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
                                        <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>3ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                    <select name="profeSustitutoTercera" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoTercera" required="true">
                                        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                        <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
                                        <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
                                        <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
                                        <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
                                        <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
                                        <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>4ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                    <select name="profeSustitutoCuarta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoCuarta" required="true">
                                        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                        <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
                                        <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
                                        <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
                                        <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
                                        <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
                                        <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>5ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                    <select name="profeSustitutoQuinta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoQuinta" required="true">
                                        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                        <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
                                        <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
                                        <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
                                        <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
                                        <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
                                        <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='centrado'>6ª</td>
                                <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
                                <td class='centrado'>
                                    <select name="profeSustitutoSexta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSexta" required="true">
                                        <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
                                        <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
                                        <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
                                        <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
                                        <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
                                        <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
                                        <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <div style="text-align:center;"> <br><input type="submit" id="ListadoSustituciones_0" value="Confirmar Sustitutos"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>   
        </body>
    </html>

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: can you post more html code i.e : `Sick` where is this combo box ? where you need to add or delete data ?

Comment: Hi @Swati ! Thanks for asking about it. I'm updating my post to include one example with 2 teachers that needs to be replaced. I will put almost all HTML code and I will put aswell the selects thats needs to be changed. Can you please help me with this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** of jquery.This method will check all the option from other select box and hide the option which is already selected.
Suppose you have selected `Tera` then this option will get hide from other `select-box` using **[hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)** method . Working code :

```js
$('select').change(function() {
var oldvar = $(this).attr('data-old') !== typeof undefined ? $(this).attr('data-old') : "";
  var newval = $("option:selected", this).val();
  //adding data-old attribute to select
  $(this).attr('data-old', newval);
  var val = $(this).val();
  var sel = $(this);

  if (val != "") {
    var otherselects = $('select').not(this).find('option');
    //checking if the value of other select option is same if yes then hide them
    otherselects.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == val;
    }).hide();
  } else if (val == "") {
    //showing option which is deselected by current select-box
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + oldvar + '"]').show();

  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> Sustituciones para <b>Robustiano</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hora</td>
        <td id="nowrap">Profesor Propuesto</td>
        <td id="nowrap">Profesor Sustituto</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>1ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.">No necesita sustituci&oacute;n.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>2ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="profeSustitutoSegunda" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSegunda" required="true">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>3ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="profeSustitutoTercera" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoTercera" required="true">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
            <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
            <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
            <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>4ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="profeSustitutoCuarta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoCuarta" required="true">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
            <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
            <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
            <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>5ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="profeSustitutoQuinta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoQuinta" required="true">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
            <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
            <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
            <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='centrado'>6ª</td>
        <td class="centrado" id="nowrap">fulanito</td>
        <td class='centrado'>
          <select name="profeSustitutoSexta" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustitutoSexta" required="true">
            <option value="">--- Selecciona Profesor ---</option>
            <option value="fulanito">fulanito</option>
            <option value="Lingüista">Lingüista</option>
            <option value="Locuaz">Locuaz</option>
            <option value="Luis">Luis</option>
            <option value="Tera">Tera</option>
            <option value="No necesita sustitución.">No necesita sustitución.</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Try below code snippet :

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var oldvar = $(this).attr('data-old') !== typeof undefined ? $(this).attr('data-old') : "";
  var newval = $("option:selected", this).val();
  //adding data-old attribute to select
  $(this).attr('data-old', newval);
  var val = $(this).val();
  var sel = $(this);

  if (val != "") {
    var otherselects = $('select').not(this).find('option');
    //checking if the value of other select option is same if yes then hide them
    otherselects.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == val;
    }).hide();
    //add this 
     $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + oldvar + '"]').show();
  } else if (val == "") {
    //showing option which is deselected by current select-box
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + oldvar + '"]').show();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati ! Thanks for your answer, it is really helpful. However, please think on this use-case: We have 3 options in 2 selects, name it A, B, C. In the first Select I choose A. That option is hide for others select's. In the second Select I choose B. That option is hide for others select's. Then I come back to 1st Select and take option C... when I come back again to 2nd Select ... the list of options are **hiding A and C**. I think this is happening but the effect is not accumulative, we only are loosing 1 option in the way to achieve this. Can you help me on this? Thank you so, so much :-)

Comment: Sorry for late response. but,according to your requirement i have made some changes in `jquery` code in above code snippet .Please check and see if that works.

Comment: Hi @Swati Sorry for so, so, so late response. These past weeks have been really awful to me and I cannot put any effort on this project. The solution you gave worked pretty fine. Thank you so, so much ;-)